# Race is to Racist as Religion is to what?

Tags: single-word-requests, nouns

Please have a one word answer; and it is not zealot. Zealots are idealists. Being a racist has a very negative connotation. Also maintain the same part of speech. I would like a noun.

Comment: I rolled back some radical edits, after the OP posted her new question elsewhere. I reclosed this as a duplicate.

Answer (score 4):

The word 'sectarian' is, of religion, closest to parallel with 'racist':

> **sectarian**
>   **B.** *n.*
>   3. A bigoted adherent of a sect; one whose views or sympathies are sectarian.

["sectarian, adj. and n.". OED Online. September 2015. Oxford University Press. http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/174583?redirectedFrom=sectarian (accessed December 08, 2015).]

'Sectarianist' is also in use. Examples include

[image]

(From [*Dialogue and Universalism*](https://books.google.com/books?id=djsKAQAAMAAJ&q=sectarianist&dq=sectarianist&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiEp7uE1MvJAhVk44MKHcJOBdU4HhDoAQgqMAM), Volume 6, Issues 7-12, Warsaw University, Centre of Universalism, 1996.) And

> Nobody who can see and write so brilliantly and fearlessly about the evils of religion as he had done would take back what he said just like that. How can a highly spiritual person like him suddenly reduce himself to a mere sectarianist?

(From [*Transcending Rizal*](https://books.google.com/books?id=Tg1xAAAAMAAJ&q=%22sectarianist%22&dq=%22sectarianist%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjtvLCOx8vJAhWtoYMKHfdKBwY4FBDoAQg3MAU), Margarita Ventenilla Hamada, Giraffe Books, 2005.)

'Sectarianist', however, has not established itself in dictionaries, although the intended meaning is clear.

Comment: Damn this guy does his research! I'm impressed.

Comment: The OP has posted her revised question here: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/293237/what-do-you-call-someone-that-hates-people-with-disabilities. I'm rolling back your edits so that it answers the original question.

Comment: So if you called someone a sectarian it would have the same effect as calling someone racist or sexist? People can be fired if they are racist or sexist. Can they be fired for being a sectarian?

Comment: @TraciGuynup, 'sectarianist' is just the word that parallels 'racist' in terms of religion. It would not be likely to have the same *force* as calling someone a racist or sexist, because the word hasn't the same cultural history or currency as those terms. But yes, people can and do get fired for *being sectarianist* (not necessarily for *being called a sectarianist*, though), because discrimination on the basis of religious beliefs is outlawed by legal systems in the US and elsewhere.

Answer (score 1):

You can use 'bigot';

> a person who strongly and unfairly dislikes other people, ideas, etc.
>   A person who hates or refuses to
>   accept the members of a particular group (such as a racial or
>   religious group).

[Dictionary](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/bigot)

Comment: Good word, and would likely serve many functions well, but I suspect that "racist" and the OP's desired word are both subcategories of "bigot."

Comment: I have been to many forum websites, especially the gaming ones. Trust me I see bigot used for this a billion times. Secterian (bigot as well) does not also serve directly for the word he is looking I believe. It is not invented for 'religiousist' people. I totally made that word up now to show my point by the way.

Comment: "Bigot" is the catch-all word for anything else that doesn't have an "__ist" equivalent.

Comment: But bigot is not specific to religion in the same way as race is to racist or sex is to sexist.